# possible to get jQuery's map not to sort?

Tags: jquery

I was not expecting jQuery's map to sort results. Is it possible to use it, or something like it, and keep the results in the same order as the source?

```js
var items = {
  "7": "AAA",
  "6": "BBB",
  "2": "CCC",
  "4": "DDD",
  "3": "EEE",
  "1": "FFF",
  "5": "GGG"
};

function ShowList(list, target) {
  $(target).append($.map(list, function (val, key) {
    return '<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>';
  }).join("\r\n"));
}

ShowList(items, '#list');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not jQuery, it's your JavaScript engine. While JavaScript objects didn't have order prior to ES2015, nearly all JavaScript engines do add some kind of order to them, and one of the most common things is to group together all properties whose names fit the definition of an array index (even though that object is not an array), and keep them in numeric order.

As of ES2015, object properties *do* have an order and certain operations in the specification are required to iterate/list them in that order (but not `Object.keys` or `for-in`, to allow for different legacy behavior). That specified order also groups together properties with names that look like array indexes, and keeps them in numeric order.¹

Regardless of ES5 and earlier or ES2015 and later, if you want those entries in the order listed in the source, your best bet is to use an array:

```js
var items = [
  {key: "7", val: "AAA"},
  {key: "6", val: "BBB"},
  {key: "2", val: "CCC"},
  {key: "4", val: "DDD"},
  {key: "3", val: "EEE"},
  {key: "1", val: "FFF"},
  {key: "5", val: "GGG"}
];

function ShowList(list, target) {
  $(target).append($.map(list, function (entry) {
    return '<li>' + entry.key + ':' + entry.val + '</li>';
  }).join("\r\n"));
}

ShowList(items, '#list');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

However, specified behavior in ES2015 would let you use an object if you used property names that didn't look like array indexes and the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` function:

```js
// ONLY RELIABLE ON A COMPLIANT ES2015+ ENGINE.
// Not recommending doing this, just noting it.
var items = {
  "p7": "AAA",
  "p6": "BBB",
  "p2": "CCC",
  "p4": "DDD",
  "p3": "EEE",
  "p1": "FFF",
  "p5": "GGG"
};

function ShowList(list, target) {
  $(target).append(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(list).map(function (key) {
    return '<li>' + key + ':' + list[key] + '</li>';
  }).join("\r\n"));
}

ShowList(items, '#list');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

---

¹ Specifically, the order of the properties is given [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) for "own" properties, and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-enumerate-object-properties) for all properties (including inherited ones):

- Own properties that look like array indexes first, in numeric order
- Own properties whose names are strings that weren't listed before, in property creation order (properties are created in the order listed in an object initializer, or of course later when you add properties to the object)
- Own properties whose names are Symbols, in creation order

If iterating/listing properties other than "own" properties, the rules above are followed first, then repeated for the prototype (skipping properties that have already been visited), then repeated for its prototype, and so on. So an object's properties come first in the order above, then any its prototype has that it doesn't (in the order above), and so on.